# Fragment Back Stack

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, back-stack

I have 3 fragments like Fragment 1, Fragment 2, Fragment 3

These all are opened using replace transaction and api is implemented in OnViewCreated in each fragment.

Now when i move from 2nd fragment to 3rd, then 2nd fragment should be removed and there should only 1st fragment in stack.

The Problem occurs is that when i move from 2nd to 3rd, the api of 3rd should be called that is working fine but along with this, api of 1st fragment is also called.

I don't want 1st fragment to be called when calling 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your 3rd Fragment will not call 1st Fragment's functionality unless you make it with viewPager or Tabs. If you do not want 2nd fragment to be in stack just remove .addToBackStack() function from your fragment attaching.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, firstFragment)
.addToBackStack(null).commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, secondFragment).commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, thirdFragment)
.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```